# howto obtain a striped table with csvloop?

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple, rowcolor

Is this possible with `csvloop` command to change the row colors in order to obtain a striped longtable?
Something equivalent to  `late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\rowcolor{white}{\\\rowcolor{gray!20}},` when we use `csvreader`

As an example, is it possible to adapt the following MWE ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
  a|b|c
  1|2|3
  4|5|6
  7|8|9
  10|11|12
  13|14|15
  16|17|18  
\end{filecontents*}

\csvloop{
  file=test.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=pipe,
  no head,
  before reading={
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \toprule
  },
  command={\csviffirstrow
    {\textbf{\csvcoli} & \textbf{\csvcolii} & \textbf{\csvcoliii} }
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }
  },
  late after line={\\},
  late after first line={\\\midrule\endhead},
  late after last line={\\\bottomrule},
  after reading={
    \end{longtable}
  }
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xcolor` package (with the `table` package option) provides the `\rowcolors` command, which is used to set alternating row colors. This command is used before you start the table, and can therefore be included in `before reading`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
  a|b|c
  1|2|3
  4|5|6
  7|8|9
  10|11|12
  13|14|15
  16|17|18  
\end{filecontents*}

\csvloop{
  file=test.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=pipe,
  no head,
  before reading={
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \toprule
  },
  command={\csviffirstrow
    {\textbf{\csvcoli} & \textbf{\csvcolii} & \textbf{\csvcoliii} }
    {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }
  },
  late after line={\\},
  late after first line={\\\midrule\endhead},
  late after last line={\\\bottomrule},
  after reading={
    \end{longtable}
  }
}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]